Incompatibility between OCC kernel and BAMG in gmsh
There seems to be an incompatibility between the OCC sphere function and the BAMG meshing algorithm. I provide the minimum working (or, rather, non-working) example below. Does anyone have a solution for this?
import gmsh

### GMSH sphere
gmsh.initialize()
gmsh.model.occ.addSphere(0, 0, 0, 1)
gmsh.model.occ.synchronize()

# BAMG (7) fails, other algorithms work
gmsh.option.setNumber("Mesh.Algorithm", 7)

gmsh.model.mesh.generate(2)

gmsh.finalize()

